# Wordpress permalink not working on subdomain

Tags: permalinks

My Wordpress permalink not working on subdomain etc :

In normally wordpress will redirect automatic like this :

[www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/?p=123](http://www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/?p=123) > [www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/post-title](http://www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/post-title)

but now my website still used plain :

[www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/?p=123](http://www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/?p=123) > [www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/?p=123](http://www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/?p=123)

How can i fix it! Thank you.

---

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Maybe all you need to do is visit the Permalink Settings page, and ensure permalinks are actually enabled.

Comment: Thank you for Reply, I try to save change on permalink setting many time. but still not working.

Comment: So does `www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/post-title` show the same post as at `www.mydomain.com/blog/post-title` (the main domain)?

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to told You, I Used different  domain on WordPress seeting Address (URL) using subdomain 1 and Site Address (URL) : subdomain 2 but subdomain 2 working normally on sub-domian2/domian.com/?p=123 to sub-domian2/domian.com/post-title

Comment: So the permalink `www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/post-title` works (it shows the correct post), but `www.sub1.mydomain.com/blog/?p=123` doesn't redirect to the permalink? Are you sure you've correctly setup the subdomain to be your WordPress address? Did you simply change the admin settings; what the exact steps you did; did you use any plugins?